# Tracing a method that is called multiple times

Tags: android

I want to trace a method that is called multiple times, but `startMethodTracing` overwrites the file when the second call is made. I tried to stop tracing it just in the end of the program, but when the nem start tracing is called it stops the early trace automatically.

Well, I could just start the tracing in the `main`, but that is not possible. There is a large amount of data, so the trace buffer overflows (already setting `bufferSize` to the maximum possible).

PS: tracing just the call of this method that I want doesn't help either because this upper method can be called multiple times too and I will have the same problem, and keep going up is not an option as the buffer overflows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean in the class that indicates if tracing has been started already. If it has, then don't call `startMethodTracing()` a second time. If it has not, then set the boolean true and start your tracing.